# Cannot remotely connect to mysql

Tags: mysql, firewall, ports

I have tried pretty much everything I could read on SO. I cannot connect remotely to my sql server. I can't even telnet to the correct port (3306). The connection just hangs. Here is a list of what I've checked/tried:

## 1) Privileges in mysql

I've run `CREATE USER 'test'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'pass';` followed by `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON db.* TO 'test'@'%';`and I flushed the changes.

## 2) Editing my.cnf

I edited the line `bind-address`to be `0.0.0.0`. I have made sure that the port is default (3306) and restarted the mysql service.

## 3) Checked firewall / that the ports are open

Using `netstat -tnlp` I checked that mysql is listening to port 3306.

To be sure, I turned off the firewall (i assume...?) using `sudo ufw disable´, and` ufw status` returns "inactive".

HOWEVER Despite all of the above, I still can't connect to my mysql server remotely. I have tried running `mysql -u test -p -h xxx` but after entering my password the connection just hangs and I get "unable to connect to remote host, connection timed out".

In addition, as mentioned above, I have attempted `telnet xxxxx 3306` from another server (where the x's denote the server IP of course), and the connection also just times out/hangs.

If you have anything else for me to try I'd LOVE to hear it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: upvote for doing your homework

Comment: where is your box, where is the server (basically)

Comment: If you mean geographically, the server I believe is hosted in Denmark? If that's not what you mean could you explain further please!

Comment: I mean, is it on aws ec2, what other firewall stuff may be in the way (security groups as they call it, if it is)

Comment: I'll have to be honest and say that I'm not 100% sure. I don't have access (yet) to where and how the server is hosted, and I'm kinda new to this stuff as well. The address is xxx.cloudapp.net, so I assume it is some kind of cloud based solution that we're using. Sorry that couldn't be of more help in that regard...

Comment: well if you don't want to fill up this page, feel free to join me in [Campaigns](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95290) and I can try to get you online with it

Comment: This question is unlikely to have anything to do with sw development, it seems pure oprational issue to me. I would ask the sysadmin / support of my server how to connect remotely to mysql.

Comment: voted to close as Too Broad (I wouldn't migrate this to a sister site). Moreover, the OP has allegely no desire to do this anymore (security risk)

Comment: transcript began at http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/31733436#31733436

Comment: change the `bind-address` back to what it was (probably `127.0.0.1`) and remove that remmed out `#skip-networking` and do a restart.

Comment: Well written question showing your efforts, so upvote for that; however, voting to close as off-topic because it's a network configuration question rather than a programming question. (For future use: If you can't get into the server machine itself, it's not going to help changing your DB settings.)